# Spring Cloud Data Flow deploy batch application to multiple cluster

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, configmap

I have two clusters in Openshift that share the same database:

- Cluster A: https://10.0.0.1:443
- Cluster B: https://10.0.0.2:443

The SCDF is installed on cluster A where I can deploy batch applications in the namespaces of this cluster previously defined in my configmap:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cm-test
  namespace: namespace
data:
  application.yaml: |
    management:
      metrics:
        export:
          prometheus:
            enabled: false
            rsocket:
              enabled: false
    spring:
      cloud:
        dataflow:
          task:
            platform:
              kubernetes: 
                accounts:
                  namespace-a:
                    namespace: namespace-a
                    entryPointStyle: exec
                  namespace-b:
                    namespace: namespace-b
                    entryPointStyle: exec
                  default:
                    entryPointStyle: exec
                    limits:
                      memory: 1024Mi
      datasource:
        url: ${DATABASE_URL}
        username: ${DATABASE_USER}
        password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
        driverClassName: ${DATABASE_DRIVER}
        initialization-mode: always
```

If I launch a task that targets Cluster A to deploy a batch application to namespace-a, how can I also deploy this task to namespace-a of Cluster B?

Would it be possible to deploy in both regions?